# How can I see HTML DOM structure via console in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, console, settings

In Chrome when I type "document" in the console, I see clearly the HTML DOM structure.

[Sreenshot HTML DOM structure Chrome when document is typed into console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rtyq.png)

When I do this in FireFox I get a bunch of extra info and it's even hard to figure out the the HTML DOM structure.

[Sreenshot HTML DOM structure FireFox when document is typed into console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoPg7.png)

My question is: Where to find or how to display the HTML DOM in FireFox the way it's displayed in Chrome?

Comment: You've specifically said "via console" so this wouldn't qualify as an answer, but if you want to see the structure as in your first screenshot, use Firefox's Inspector tab rather than console. In the console, it's showing you the properties of the object (like any other object), whereas Chrome's dev tools team decided showing the DOM structure was more useful.

Comment: Still the best answer so far ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check this. maybe helpful.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DOM_Property_Viewer

Once enabled, you can open the DOM Property Viewer by selecting "DOM" from the Web Developer submenu in the Firefox Menu Panel (or Tools menu if you display the menu bar or are on macOS), or by pressing its `Ctrl + Shift + W` keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It doesn't seem to show anything useful though. To see the structure, you still have to click the little nubbins, which just takes you to the Inspector panel.

Comment: Agree the DOM section doesn't show the structure. What do you mean by the nubbins?